# Dynamically create CGridViews that show different data

Tags: yii, cgridview

I'm new to Yii, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.  I want to show multiple CGridViews on a page depending on the options that a user chooses, with each gridview only showing the records for that option.  In this case, the options are job statuses, like open, closed, in progress, etc.

I've got some code working to show multiple grid views by looping through an array, but I'm not sure how to filter them:

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach ($test as $value) {

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),   
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        'CustomerCompany',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        /* etc */
    ),
));

}
```

Any ideas about how I can go about filtering each gridview from the values in the array?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Ok, I figured out how to do what I was trying to do.  I'm handling it in the controller like this:

```
public function actionBoard()
{
    $models = array();

    $statuses = JobStatus::model()->findAll();
    foreach ($statuses as $status)
    {
    $model=new Job('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

    if(isset($_GET['Job']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Job'];
        $model->Status = $status->ID;
        $models[$status->Status] = $model;
    }

    $this->render('board',array('models'=>$models));
}
```

So I find all the statuses, then use the ID field to do a search, put the result in an array, then pass it to the view.  I handle it like this in the view:

```
foreach ($models as $status)
{

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$status->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        'CustomerCompany',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        'Phone1',
        'Phone2',
        /* etc */
    ),
));
```

Basically, creating a gridview for each "status" in the array of "statuses".  Seems to work, just took some time to think of it in MVC terms instead of the old ASP.NET databinding method that I'm used to.

Comment: I think you just need one CGridViews and you can update the table by ajax when choose options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for different CGridViews, so here it is:

Go in your model.

Now, you need to write some new search() methods.

Within each method, you will specify the values that you want, like these 2 methods:

```
public function searchA() {
// Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
// should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);
        $criteria->compare('password', $this->password);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created);
        $criteria->compare('lastmodified', $this->lastmodified);
        $criteria->compare('confirmed', $this->confirmed);
        $criteria->compare('is_human', 1);// this is a human

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

    public function searchB() {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);
        $criteria->compare('password', $this->password);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created);
        $criteria->compare('lastmodified', $this->lastmodified);
        $criteria->compare('confirmed', $this->confirmed);
        $criteria->compare('is_human', 0);//this is not a human, maybe a donkey ... who knows
        $criteria->compare('username', $this->username, true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

now that you have your search methods, use the needed search method for each cgridview

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchA(),   
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        'CustomerCompany',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        /* etc */
    ),
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'job-grid2',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchB(),   
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        'CustomerCompany',
        'FirstName',
        'LastName',
        /* etc */
    ),
));
```

simple

ps: as a trick, you may want to use constants, like:

```
const CONSTA = 1;
const CONSTB = 2;
```

and use then in the model as:

```
self::CONSTA
```

or outside the model as:

```
ModelName::CONSTA
```

by using const, if your values change in time, you dont have to modify the entire code and you dont have to look all over the project for those values

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up doing it with the Search method on my Job model, but I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You should begin at the data part of the problem: First try to create several data providers that return the results that you want. If you used **Gii** to auto-generate some models, you can look into the `search()` method there to see an example how you can create such a provider with different query conditions. You should try to keep this code in a model somewhere. For example you could create a `searchByStatus($status)` method, which returns a data provider for the given status.

Then in the controller you can fetch several data providers from this method, one for each status you want, send them to the view and finally feed them into different CGridViews.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wiki for [dynamic gridviews](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/323/dynamic-parent-and-child-cgridview-on-single-view-using-ajax-to-update-child-gridview-via-controller-after-row-in-parent-gridview-was-clicked) in the same view.